# What would be the best join to accomplish my end data?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #C
(grpType varchar(10),
CPTCode varchar(10) NULL,
Month int NULL,
MTD money NULL,
MonthCount int NULL,
YTD money NULL,
YearCount int NULL,
Code varchar(10) NULL)
```

With the following data in it:

```
grpType CPTCode Month   MTD MonthCount  YTD YearCount   Code
Month   76800   5   1321.61  27       6574.54   82        76800
Month   76856   5   246.01   3        380.64    6         76856
Month   76881   5   9778.95  131          50682.59  509       76881
Month   76942   5   22467.33 190         116663.58  674       76942
```

Then I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE #Prod
(grpType varchar(10),
TotalCharges money NULL,
TotalUnits float NULL,
RVU float NULL,
Code varchar(10) NULL,
CPTCode varchar(10) NULL)
```

With this data:

```
grpType TotalCharges    TotalUnits  RVU Code    CPTCode
Month   6100.00           12             0  76800   76800
Month   -475.00           -1             0  76880   76880
Month   38749.00      81             0  76881   76881
Month   54733.00      114            0  76942   76942
```

What I need is my end data to look like this:

```
CPTCode     MTD     TotalCharges     TotalUnits
76800       1321.61  6100.00           12
76856       246.01    NULL             NULL
76880       NULL     -475.00           -1
76881       9778.95  38749.00          81
76942       22467.33 54733.00          114
```

What would be the best join to achieve this?  I have tried the left join and it doesn't work I get this result:

```
CPTCode MTD TotalCharges    TotalUnits
76800   1321.61   6100.00   12
76881   9778.95   38749.00  81
76942   22467.33  54733.00  114
```

Which excludes some of the data and that I do not want.  Are there any suggestions from anyone?

Thank you

Here is the query that doesn't work:

```
 SELECT
#C.CPTCode,
#C.MTD,
#Prod.TotalCharges,
#Prod.TotalUnits
FROM  
#C
LEFT JOIN #Prod ON #C.grpType = #Prod.grpType AND #C.Code = #Prod.Code
WHERE
   (#C.CPTCode = '76800' OR #C.CPTCode = '76856' OR #C.CPTCode = '76880' OR #C.CPTCode = '76881' OR #C.CPTCode = '76942' OR #C.CPTCode = '93922')
```

Comment: Show us your query where your `JOIN` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide the query you currently have?

Comment: I added it to the original question

Comment: Can Code and CPTCode be different?  They appear to be duplicate columns in both tables.

Comment: No I just noticed that as well that they appear to be duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with the help of Chad Cook and some other friends around the internet.  This is the final join that we came up with and the output is perfect.

```
SELECT
  ISNULL(c.CPTCode, p.CPTCode) as CPTCode,
  c.MTD,
  p.TotalCharges,
  p.TotalUnits
FROM
 #C c 
  FULL OUTER JOIN #Prod p
     ON c.grpType = p.grpType AND c.CPTCode = p.CPTCode
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can have an "optional" entry in either table.  If this is the case you will need to use an full outer join.  The left join will only work it you are guaranteed an entry in the #Prod table, but 76856 does not exist in #Prod and is thus excluded.  A right join would also not work as 76880 does not exist in #C and would be excluded.

Comment: That is it!  The only problem is that the negative values are not showing up why would that be?

Comment: What does your output look like now?